# Scrape metrics from prometheus that were written with remote_write

Tags: prometheus

Is it possible to send metrics to one or more prometheus instances using remote write, and then have a central prometheus instance scrape those metrics?

I have a simple prometheus config

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     10s
  evaluation_interval: 10s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
```

I start up prometheus enabling remote write

```
docker run -p 9090:9090 -v /prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml  --enable-feature=remote-write-receiver
```

I can then push metrics to this instance using remote write.  When I browse to the UI http://localhost:9090 I can query the metrics.

But what I'd like to do is have another prometheus instance with centralized storage scrape them.
I've looked at the metrics endpoint http://localhost:9090/metrics but this only contains metrics for the prometheus instance, not metrics that were pushed to the instance.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take your time for a [tour], and look through [help/on-topic].

Comment: Your question being about configuration is considered off-topic. It will be more appropriate for one of [devops.se], [sf] or [su] (look through their respective help pages to find most appropriate for your situation)

Comment: But in short, you are looking for feature called [federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/).

Comment: Thanks @markalex.  The /federate endpoint does exactly what I need.